# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column does not exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### model

Attempt 1

```
def challenge_date
   deadline || date_started  
end
```

Attempt 2

```
def challenge_date
  if deadline != date_started
    [deadline, date_started].reject(&:blank?).join()
  else
    date_started
  end
end
```

Both attempts gave the error. I need the method to iterate through `next_user_challenge`

```
def next_user_challenge
  user.challenges.where('challenge_date > ?', challenge_date).order('challenge_date ASC').first
end
```

### rails c

```
# some challenges will just have a deadline
 id: 1,
 name: "Publish a Novel",
 deadline: Sat, 26 Nov 2016,
 date_started: nil,
 user_id: 117,

# some challenges will just have a date_started
 id: 2,
 name: "Write a Chp",
 deadline: nil,
 date_started: Thu, 20 Oct 2016,
 user_id: 117,

# and some challenges will have both
 id: 3,
 name: "Run a Mile",
 deadline: Thu, 26 Sep 2016,
 date_started: Thu, 26 Sep 2016, # If challenge has both deadline and date_started then date_started will be the same date as the deadline
 user_id: 117,
```

Comment: `challenge_date` is a method, so you can't to a database query on it.  How is it meant to determine which challenge is next when comparing those with a start date and those with a deadline?

Comment: is `next_user_challenge` a method on your `User` model? Can you also clarify which date you want to compare with the deadline/start date of the challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a postgres query but you can achieve it rails way

```
def next_user_challenge
  user.challenges.select{ |ch| ch.challenge_date > challenge_date }.sort_by(&:challenge_date).first
end
```

**NOTE:** This will fetch all challenges from db and then select the valid one.

I will suggest creating a new column in challenges table and using ActiveModal callbacks to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using not database model attribute to query the data and of course it will not work.

To solve this problem, there are 2 ways:

1. Use [Deepak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40357691/3295520) way
2. Use raw SQL query, in this way, you should prepare `challenge_date` and join with self table to process other query.